# Data Array Decimation

Tags: c, arrays, reduce

I have an array which is changing rapidly and has variable length -this could be 100 minimum and about 5k maximum-. And i'm going to use these values to encolouring a data column that i produce by drawing lines one by one. This will be something like scan graph.

And another thing is, i have a fixed column length but variable data array length, so every member of the array should be fit into the graph. If the length of the data is less than column length, i should expand the array which is easier one and i did that. But if the length of the data is bigger, i have to do something like decimation.

The problem is, i should keep the characteristic of the array during the decimation. When i tried to calculate the arithmetic mean the group of every N member, the graph is getting smoother which i don't want to.

What should i do to fit this array into the graph, without change it's characteristic?

This is how the graph looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRCf4.jpg

Comment: Could you show more precisely what you did to calculate the decimation ? What is N ? Do you want to rescale the data array length to fit in the graph ?

Comment: The calculation of a mean by definition will smooth things. If that's not the effect you want, you need to use a function other than the mean. Some possibilities would be things like selecting the first, last, middle or some other representative point (possibly at random) out of the window...

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind to keep the sharpness of the graph is to keep the value in the group of N that is the further from the one in the previous column.

Comment: Yes, @chmike rescaling the data array length to fit in the graph is definitely what i want to do. But in the same time, i want to keep the sharpness of the data that comes from rapidly changing. And N is the rescaling factor, basically (the wide of the graph / data count). twalberg, selecting points randomly makes sense, but it might affect the sharpness anyway, doesn't it? Joël Hecht, can explain this a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean that your relevant information is the location of spikes and their height. So you want to rescale the graph while preserving the spikes and their height.

One way to achieve that is to remove data points with minimal value difference with its neighbours. You could compute a score for each data point that is proportional to the difference of its value with its neighbour and decimate the data points with smallest score. A candidate score function is the sum of the square of difference.

You then create a score vector as big as your data vector and for each data value you compute its score like this

```
score[i] = square(data[i]-data[i-1]) + square(data[i+1]-data[i]);
```

Another candidate is

```
score[i] = abs(data[i]-data[i-1]) + abs(data[i+1]-data[i]);
```

You also want that this decimation is applied as uniformly as possible over your data so that the graph doesn't become distorted. One way to achieve this is to split your data into buckets and decimate in each buckets the required number of data points.

If you have to remove many data points (N > 2), it might be preferable to do it in multiple pass where each pass recomputes the score. In this case you don't distort to much the content of each buckets.

Comment: Actually it might work perfect. I was looking for a way to remove points with some kind of neighbourhood realationship but to be honest, i couldn't do the math. Then the next math operation i have to do is splitting data into a buckets according to my rescaling factor, and do this operations within this sections. Really appreciate for your helps @chmike, i guess i'm going to vote this for accepted answer.